# grouped products in magento not displaying properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

i'm having a weird problem here. i migrated my Magento store to a new host and after fixing heaps of stuff to make it work i still have one more problem that i couldn't find the solution for it. all products are displaying properly accept the grouped products, the options are not displaying at all, the buy now button is not displaying, the yotpo review/rating widget is not displaying, the tabs at the bottom are not displaying.
check this link: http://www.simplysterling.com.au/iphone-6-6-plus-cover-plastic-gel-transparent-color-flower-lilo-stitch-diamond.html

now going to the back-end everything looks fine the associated products are there and i can't find any problems.

is that a code error or a Database error?
any one knows the solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like memory limit is exceed. Check your `memory_limit` configuration in your php.ini file. It is less than 64MB then try to increase upto 254 or 512MB and check again.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Elavarasan .the php memory is 512 MB so i don't think this is the problem. beside that all other pages are working fine. Thanks